# Ansible Container unable to load libsudo_util.so.0 for privileged module execution

Tags: docker, ansible, debian, sudo, ansible-container

I am trying to use Ansible Container for a basic example which is supposed to install Node within the image. When I use the `ansible-container build` command, after successfully building the conductor image, it fails the first task with a `sudo` related error. The task in question requires `root` privileges to be executed.

I am running Debian GNU/Linux 9.2 (stretch) with Docker 17.09.0-ce installed through the Docker APT repository. I tried with Ansible both from Debian Stretch (2.2.1.0-2) and from Pypi (2.4.1.0). I tried Ansible Container from Pypi (0.9.3rc0) and from the latest Git source. I always get the exact same error output.

The Ansible module complains about the following:

```
sudo: error while loading shared libraries: libsudo_util.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The task being run looks like the following:

```
- name: Add the Node Source repository signing certificate to APT
  apt_key:
    id: 9FD3B784BC1C6FC31A8A0A1C1655A0AB68576280
    keyserver: hkps://hkps.pool.sks-keyservers.net
  become: yes
```

Both the conductor as well as the service I try to create use the `debian:stretch` base image.

I am running the `ansible-container build` command with `sudo` prepended, because only `root` may access the Docker socket on my system.

Here is the content of my `container.yml`:

```
version: "2"
settings:
  conductor:
    base: debian:stretch
  project_name: container_test
services:
  nodejs:
    from: debian:stretch
    roles:
      - nodejs
registries: {}
```

Here is the full error output:

```
Building Docker Engine context...
Starting Docker build of Ansible Container Conductor image (please be patient)...
Parsing conductor CLI args.
Docker™ daemon integration engine loaded. Build starting.       project=container_test
Building service...     project=container_test service=nodejs

PLAY [nodejs] ******************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
ok: [nodejs]

TASK [nodejs : Add the Node Source repository signing certificate to APT] ******
fatal: [nodejs]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "sudo: error while loading shared libraries: libsudo_util.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "rc": 127}
        to retry, use: --limit @/tmp/tmpTRBQDe/playbook.retry

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
nodejs                     : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1

ERROR   Error applying role!    engine=<container.docker.engine.Engine object at 0x7f84da0c5ed0> exit_code=2 playbook=[{'hosts': u'nodejs', 'roles': ['nodejs'], 'vars': {}}]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/conductor", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('ansible-container', 'console_scripts', 'conductor')()
  File "/_ansible/container/__init__.py", line 19, in __wrapped__
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/_ansible/container/cli.py", line 408, in conductor_commandline
    **params)
  File "/_ansible/container/__init__.py", line 19, in __wrapped__
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/_ansible/container/core.py", line 843, in conductorcmd_build
    raise RuntimeError('Build failed.')
RuntimeError: Build failed.
Conductor terminated. Cleaning up.      command_rc=1 conductor_id=e8899239ad1017a89acc97396d38ab805d937a7b3d74e5a7d2741d7b1124bb0c save_container=False
ERROR   Conductor exited with status 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the cause for this:

The base image `debian:stretch` does not include `sudo`. Therefore a solution was to set the `become_method` to `su` instead. Normally, this can either be done per task, host or playbook. Because it is not obvious where the equivalent of a playbook lies in Ansible Container and how the concept of hosts applies, I only really had the option to use the task level.

I decided to add a role which installs `sudo` in the image and only set the `become_method` to `su` for the solitary task within this role. Atfer the role is applied, no further change is needed and the original tasks work.

A follow-up problem then was, that also GnuPG was not installed either to accomplish the `apt_key` module task properly. The following solution solves both problems:

```
- become: yes
  become_method: su
  block:
    - name: Update package cache
      apt:
        update_cache: yes
        cache_valid_time: 86400

    - name: Install GnuPG
      package:
        name: gnupg2
        state: present

    - name: Install sudo
      package:
        name: sudo
        state: present
```

Supposedly a more clean option would be to generate a base image that already includes these dependencies to allow for a more streamlined Ansible Container image generation.